# let $f( x + \frac{ 1}{ x } ) = x ^ 2 + \frac{ 1}{ x ^ 2} $ then $f(x)$ equals

Tags: functional-equations

let $f( x + \frac{ 1}{ x } ) = x ^ 2 + \frac{ 1}{ x ^ 2} $ then $f(x)$ equals

> options are

$( A ) x ^ 2 - 2$

$( B ) x ^  2 - 1$

$( C ) x ^ 2$

> I don't know how to solve this type of problems

Comment: What have you tried? A very simple way to attempt this is just plug in all the answer choices for $f(x)$ in order to find the right function. If you do not know how to solve the problem, you have to check again your textbook (if available) or ask your teacher. A guide to ask a good question can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question).

Comment: Taking $x=1$ we see that $f(2)=2$ so...

Comment: @TrầnThúcMinhTrí can these type of questions ask in subjective papers I mean without options?

Comment: I actually don't know much about functions, but by looking at your multiple choice questions I can still get some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is A. Just substitute $f(x+\frac 1x)$ in option A and verify the outcome

$$f(x+\frac 1x)=(x+\frac 1x)^2-2=x^2+\frac {1}{x^2}$$

So this outcome is only possible if $f(x)=x^2-2$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Note that $(a+b)^2 =a^2 +2ab +b^2$. Now let $a=x$ and $b=1/x$. Then relate $f(x+\frac1x)$ with $(x+\frac1x)^2$ somehow.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x+\frac1x)=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$

Let's run through the options.

First, let's try $A$. $f(x)=x^2-2$

Thus
$$f(x+\frac 1x)=(x+\frac 1x)^2-2$$
Evaluating the $RHS$ we get:
$$(x+\frac1x)^2-2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}+2-2=x^2+\frac{1}{x^2}$$
as required.
No need, therefore, to check $B$ and $C$.

Answer (score 0):

Lets to this the mathematical way. Let $a=x+\frac 1x$. Simply $f(a) = a^2-2$.
Now by obvious bijection and no known constraints, one to one mapping will obviously show $f(x) = x^2-2$.

So choose options A.

This seems a more complete answer, as OP requires if **no options were provided**.